# Как WCF служба может узнать, что клиент отсоединился?

Tags: c#, wcf

Когда клиент хочет отредактировать запись, то шлется запрос WCF службе, что бы она в свою очередь обновила статус этой записи в БД на "редактируется", что бы другие клиенты с ней ничего не могли сделать на время редактирования.

Так вот, если неожиданно клиент отрубился(пропал интернет и все такое), как WCF служба может узнать, что клиента, который производил редактирование, больше нет и нужно вернуть статус на доступно?

А что если деструктор на стороне службы сделать? По идее если клиент не отвечает долгое время, то его экземпляр умирает и тут в дело приходит мой деструктор , который разблокирует записи, если такие есть

Comment: Блокирование записи для редакторование - это плохое решение для веб сценария. *Optimistic concurrency control* - намного больше подходит. Обычно в каждой таблице используется *immutable* (не изменяемый `id`), например, int `IDENTITY` и создается поле типа [rowversion NOT NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/ms182776(v=sql.120).aspx), которое посылаенся клиенту вместе с данными. Значение поле `rowversion NOT NULL` увеличивается автоматически при каждой модификации. Поэтому, проверка неизменности `rowversion` является гарантией того, что запись не модифицирована другим пользователем.

Comment: Автор, вам же уже ответили. Вы бы написали что с этими ответами не так...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этих целей лучше использовать класс [IChannelInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ichannelinitializer.aspx) - класс, предназначенный для детектирования подключения клиентов, в котором вы можете установить события на закрытие канала(чтобы не писать их в каждой реализации метода службы)

Например, создадим класс `ClientTrackerChannelInitializer`, который наследует интерфейс `IChannelInitializer`.

```
    class ClientTrackerChannelInitializer : IChannelInitializer
    {
        internal static int ConnectedClientCount = 0;

        // метод, который определяет, что клиент подсоединился, создался новый канал
        public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel)
        {
            ConnectedClientCount++;
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} initialized", channel.SessionId);
            channel.Closed += ClientDisconnected;
            channel.Faulted += ClientDisconnected;
        }
        // событие, на которое подписались при создании канала
        static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client {0} disconnected", ((IClientChannel)sender).SessionId);
            ConnectedClientCount--;
        }
    }
```

У него два метода

- *Initialize* - метод, который срабатывает при подключении нового
  клиента
- *ClientDisconnected* - метод, обработчик события закрытия
  канала(или ошибки в канале)

Теперь необходимо подключить класс `ClientTrackerChannelInitializer` на стороне сервера. Для этого создадим класс, реализующий интерфейс [IEndpointBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx), класс,  который позволяет расширять поведение конечной точки службы

```
    class ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            // подключаем наш класс 
            endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ChannelInitializers.Add(new ClientTrackerChannelInitializer());
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
```

В методе `ApplyDispatchBehavior` мы подключили класс ClientTrackerChannelInitializer. 
Все классы созданы. Теперь можно публиковать службу. 
Предположим, что у нас есть сервис `IStackCalculator`. Класс 
`StackCalculator` реализует данный сервис

```
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IStackCalculator
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Enter(double value);
        [OperationContract]
        double Add();
        [OperationContract]
        double Subtract();
        [OperationContract]
        double Multiply();
        [OperationContract]
        double Divide();
    }
```

Теперь при публикации хоста сервиса подключим наше расширение конечной точки.

```
     string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
     ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StackCalculator), new Uri(baseAddress));
     WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
     binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;
     ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStackCalculator), binding, "");
     // подключаем расширение конечной точки службы
     endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior());
     host.Open();
     Console.WriteLine("Host opened");
```

Теперь при соединении/отключении клиентов будут срабатывать события `Initialize` и 
`ClientDisconnected` нашего класса `ClientTrackerChannelInitialize`. Нет необходимости прописывать подписывание на событие закрытия канала в самой реализации метода.

Механизм создания классов-расширения служб, реализующих интерфейс `IEndpointBehaviour`, можно применять для многих целей. По своему опыту применял для подсчета количества вызовов функций сервиса, для замера скорости выполнения функции сервиса, для аутентификации пользователя... 
Посмотрите [Примеры использования IEndpointBehavior](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/04/wcf-extensibility-iendpointbehavior/).

Более подробно о примере, который мы рассмотрели, можно прочитать [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2012/02/13/wcf-extensibility-initializers-instance-context-channel-call-context/).
[Пример кода](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-initializers-344bce44)

P.S. Если необходимо подключить кастомный IEndpointBehavior через файл config, напишите, добавлю в ответ.

**Edit:** Чтобы подключить наш класс-расширение конечной точки `ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior`, мы должны сделать следующее

1. Зарегистрировать наше поведение в
   *< system.servicemodel >/< extensions >/< behaviorExtensions >* указав имя расширения и тип класса, реализующего расширение(тип класса
   `ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior`)

   < extensions >
      < behaviorExtensions>
         < add name="clientTracker" 
    
           type="ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior, Client.ExtensionsDLL /> 
    
      < /behaviorExtensions>
2. Добавить расширение конечной точки в элементе [< behaviors >](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731298(v=vs.110).aspx). Здесь мы в качестве расширения указываем элемент-расширение `clientTracker`, которое определили на предыдущем шаге

   < behaviors>
         < endpointBehaviors>
           < behavior name="ServiceBehaviorExtension">
             < clientTracker /> 
           < /behavior>
         < /endpointBehaviors>
    < /behaviors>
3. Теперь при определении конечной точки сервиса мы можем подключить поведение через атрибут [behaviourConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731320(v=vs.110).aspx), указав имя расширения, указанного выше

   < services>
         < service name="StackCalculator" >
           < endpoint name="endpoint1"
                     address=""
                     binding="basicHttpBinding"
                     bindingName="binding"
                     contract="IStackCalculator"
                     behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorExtension" 
                      / >
   ...
   < /services >

Пример можно посмотреть например [отсюда](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/customwcfbehaviorsthroughappconfig)

Comment: опишите, как это выглядет в config файле

Comment: @iluxa1810, обновил ответ. P.S Прощу прощения за отсутствие форматирования xml config-a, почему то он у меня не форматируется как пример кода. Но оно должно быть понятно

Comment: Может быть, подключение атрибутом получится более красивым?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, здесь мы через атрибут и подключаем. Или что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Нет, тут вы подключаете вручную и через конфиг. Атрибутов я вообще не нашел.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, а я смогу с помощью этого словить событие на стороне службы, если оператор сделал Ctrl+Alt+Del и завершил клиент? Я ,немного, эксперементировал с событиями и  вот это не поймало событие закрытия приложения `            if (channel == null)
            {
                channel = OperationContext.Current.Channel;
                channel.Closed += UnlockDictionary;
                channel.Faulted += UnlockDictionary;
            }` ,

Comment: @iluxa1810 закрытие будет поймано по истечению тайм-аута. Про настройку тайм-аутов я писал в своем ответе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, согласен, можно сделать таким образом. Dispose будет вызываться у сервиса, когда клиент отключился.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, что касается вопроса подключения расширения для конечной точки через атрибут. Endpointbehavior может быть задан только через config/code. через атрибут нельзя, как например для ServiceBehavior.[http://geekswithblogs.net/BizTalkAndOtherTechs/archive/2013/11/08/difference-between-servicebehavior-and-endpointbehavior.aspx](http://geekswithblogs.net/BizTalkAndOtherTechs/archive/2013/11/08/difference-between-servicebehavior-and-endpointbehavior.aspx)

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, несколько вопросов: 1) Во втором шаге Client.ExtensionsDLL - это название сборки, откуда берется этот тип? Если тип находится в одном проекте, то я игнорирую это ? 2)Немного,непонял во втором шаге, где я должен прописать clientTracker ?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, я разобрался. Спасибо. Еще нужно наследовать от BehaviorExtensionElement, что бы расширение работало.

Comment: Я так понимаю, если вызывается Faulted, то в тот же момент вызывается Closed, и в консоль пишется Disconnected два раза; Т.е. метод ClientDisconnected вызывается два раза, что не хорошо; Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: @Arasfon, в моем примере на Fault и Closed навешен один и тот же обработчик - метод ClientDisconnected. Создайте отдельный метод-обработчик для события Fault и метод ClientDisconnected не будет вызываться на событие Fault.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен элемент привязки `reliableSession`. Этот элемент привязки, помимо прочих функций, периодически посылает сообщения для поддержания соединения в активном состоянии.

У элемента привязки `reliableSession` есть настройка `inactivityTimeout`. Она задает период времени, в течении которого этот элемент ожидает сообщений с другого конца соединения прежде чем сказать что соединение закрылось. При этом сам он периодически посылает "пустые" сообщения для поддержания соединения.

Внимательнее будьте с настройкой `receiveTimeout`. Она задает интервал времени, в течении которого сервис ожидает хоть одного непустого сообщения. Значение здесь должно быть как минимум раз в десять выше, чем значение `inactivityTimeout` - иначе весь смысл `reliableSession` теряется.

**UPDATE**

Теперь как отслеживать соединение/отсоединение клиента. Самый простой способ - использовать `[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]` и `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]`, при этом реализовать интерфейс `IDisposable`.

При подключении нового клиента будет вызван конструктор сервиса, при отключении (нормальном либо аварийном) - метод `Dispose()`.

**UPDATE**

Пример фрагмента конфига привязки:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding receiveTimeout="01:00:00">
        <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="false" inactivityTimeout="00:00:15" />
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Достаточно настройки привязки, остальные настройки менять не нужно. Настройки привязки на клиенте и сервере должны совпадать (либо быть совместимы - но проще чтобы совпадали).

Скорее всего, у вас `binding` будет иметь также атрибут `name`. Атрибут `ordered="false"` не обязателен, привел его для примера. Он отвечает за то, будет ли `reliableSession` следить за порядком сообщений.

Comment: А можешь примеры конфигов клиента и службы приложить?

Comment: @iluxa1810 я даже не знаю какими транспортами вы пользуетесь

Comment: Использую wsHttpBinding.

Comment: Почему-то ловлю такое исключение: Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.

Comment: @iluxa1810 в каком месте вы его ловите? Я думаю, тут надо или отдельный вопрос задавать - или в чат перехрдить. Потому что это уже не по теме.

Comment: Я отдельный вопрос создал: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/510567/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B2-wcf

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант клиенту дергать метод WCF службы, который говорит, что "вот я в сети" с периодичностью скажем 5-15 минут. Если инет падает у клиента, он метод не дергает, а значит служба через 5-15 минут меняет в БД статус.

**Дополнение к ответу**

Можно прочекать отвалился ли клиент так:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WcfServiceLibrary1
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            ClientConnected();
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
        private void ClientConnected()
        {
           IContextChannel objClientHandle = OperationContext.Current.Channel;
           objClientHandle.Faulted += new EventHandler(this.ClientDisconnected);
        }

        private void ClientDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var context = (IContextChannel)sender; // вот тут будет понятно, что клиент отрубился.
            // Тестил я так - установил таймаут на биндинге - называется он <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:00:15" /> в конфиге.
            // Через 15 сек клиент отваливается и кидает сюда.
        }
    }
}
```

Вот на всякий случай как прописать таймаут, чтобы протестить, с реальным дисконнектом не тестил:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
      <reliableSession inactivityTimeout="00:00:15" />
      <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation"
                 requireSecurityContextCancellation="true">
      </security>
      <compositeDuplex />
      <oneWay />
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12WSAddressing10" writeEncoding="utf-8" />
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm=""
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: В принципе, работать будет. Но неужели нет более красивых приемов? Если не ошибаюсь, то служба создает на каждого клиента свой экземпляр. На стороне службы таймер нельзя запустить? Т.е вот я вызываю метод на WCF службе, который меняет статус записи и WCF запускает таймер.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, мб поможет.

Comment: А что если деструктор на стороне службы сделать? По идее если клиент не отвечает долгое время, то его экземпляр умирает и тут в дело приходит мой деструктор , который разблокирует записи, если такие есть