# Как обработать исключение связанную с каналом в WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть WCF служба, которая работает в сессионном режиме.

В конфиге стоит inactivityTimeout=15 сек.

Если юзер некорректно завершает работу клиента, то через 15 секунд на стороне службы вылетает исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне его перехватить на стороне службы?

Comment: А что при этом в стеке вызовов?

Comment: Похоже- это мой косяк. Я врубил срабатывание на все возможные исключения в настройках дебагера, даже если они перехватываются.